# Aperiodic hexagonal tiling?

Tags: tiling, tessellations

Is there any known [aperiodic tiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperiodic_tiling) of the plane using hexagons?

[Wang tiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_tile) are a known aperiodic tiling using squares.  I'm looking for something similar using hexagons.

Comment: A quick Google search turned up http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.4279/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick Google search turned up http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.4279/

Comment: And briefly looking through that paper, I'm stunned at how pretty their tilings are. They chose very aesthetically pleasing ways to record their tilings.

Answer (score 1):

Page 13 of ["A chiral aperiodic monotile" (Smith, Myers, Kaplan, Goodman-Strauss 2023)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.17743) — the "spectre" paper — shows that the supertile structure of the spectre tiling is basically this marked-hexagon tiling. (These tiles are one-sided; don't include their reflections.)

[image]

[image]

[Robert Israel's earlier answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/185506/121469) points to ["An aperiodic hexagonal tile"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.4279) (Socolar, Taylor 2010), which is a *single* marked hexagon (plus its reflection). Its supertile structure (IIUC) is a simple Sierpinski-triangle pattern:

[image]

And even though I know you meant *regular* hexagons, I can't resist pointing out that this tiling, from Chaim Goodman-Strauss's slides on ["Aperiodic Hierarchical Tilings,"](https://strauss.hosted.uark.edu/distribution/talks/aperiodicity.pdf) is both aperiodic and based on a six-sided polygon. :)

[image]

[image]